# Apache Velocity : Velocity.getTemplate fails to load the vm file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, velocity

I know that it could be a very basic issue but i am stuck for sometime and need help. I have created  a maven project in IntelliJ for testing Apache Velocity.

Directory Structure

- project/src/main/java/CodeGenerator.java
- project/src/main/resources/test.vm

For some reason, I am getting "SEVERE: ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'test.vm' in any resource loader." exception.

I tried setting resource class and other options available on internet and it failed. I am sure i am missing something obvious but not able to figure it out yet.

Any help  or how to tutorials ?

```
public class CodeGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
        velocityEngine.init();
        Template template = null;
        //template = Velocity.getTemplate("resources/test.vm"); //not working
       // template = Velocity.getTemplate("test.vm");  //not working
        template = Velocity.getTemplate("/src/main/resources/test.vm"); // This is working now - 
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it .. It should be  Velocity.getTemplate("/src/main/resources/test.vm") - full path

Comment: You could also use Velocity.getTemplate("/test.vm");

Comment: @Karim: It failed.

Comment: Try again, but before set some properties for the classpath :
velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
velocityEngine.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());

It works just fine for me!

Comment: I agree, I tried the above mentioned statements. But for some reason it kept on failing. Now also, it failed. I believe it is something to do with Environment or build tool ( IntelliJ ? maven  ?)

Comment: I'm using the same code and it's working perfectly, I can't tell where your problem is ><